# How to get a "detailed" describe() in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

So, I got a questionary and I'll replicate 2 columns here:

```
Range       Answer
>30          maybe
>30          yes
<30          no
<30          yes
>30          maybe
<30          yes
```

So what I need to do, is to group by Range and know how many answers of each option each get, in this case:

```
Range       Answer
<30          
             no: 1
             yes:2
             maybe:0
>30          
             no: 0
             yes:1
             maybe:2
```

In reality, there are not 2 columns but many of them and I need to group-by one of them and then get that kind of statistics for each other column in the dataframe. This is the first time I work with categorical data and I'm quite lost. I used describe() and it works for the most common answer but I need it for every answer, is there a direct method like a "detailed desceibe()"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) for reshape with aggregate[`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) :

```
print (df)
  Range Answer1 Answer2 Answer3
0   >30   maybe      no     yes
1   >30     yes     yes      no
2   <30      no     yes      no
3   <30     yes   maybe      no
4   >30   maybe      no     yes
5   <30     yes      no      no
```

---

```
print (df.melt('Range', var_name='Answers', value_name='Vals'))
   Range  Answers   Vals
0    >30  Answer1  maybe
1    >30  Answer1    yes
2    <30  Answer1     no
3    <30  Answer1    yes
4    >30  Answer1  maybe
5    <30  Answer1    yes
6    >30  Answer2     no
7    >30  Answer2    yes
8    <30  Answer2    yes
9    <30  Answer2  maybe
10   >30  Answer2     no
11   <30  Answer2     no
12   >30  Answer3    yes
13   >30  Answer3     no
14   <30  Answer3     no
15   <30  Answer3     no
16   >30  Answer3    yes
17   <30  Answer3     no
```

---

```
df1 = df.melt('Range', var_name='Answers', value_name='Vals') \
        .groupby(['Range', 'Answers', 'Vals']).size()
print (df1)
Range  Answers  Vals 
<30    Answer1  no       1
                yes      2
       Answer2  maybe    1
                no       1
                yes      1
       Answer3  no       3
>30    Answer1  maybe    2
                yes      1
       Answer2  no       2
                yes      1
       Answer3  no       1
                yes      2
dtype: int64
```

Another solution is use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for reshape and use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('Range').stack() \
        .groupby(level=[0,1]).value_counts()
print (df1)
Range                
<30    Answer1  yes      2
                no       1
       Answer2  maybe    1
                no       1
                yes      1
       Answer3  no       3
>30    Answer1  maybe    2
                yes      1
       Answer2  no       2
                yes      1
       Answer3  yes      2
                no       1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: The use of melt was simply brilliant, Simple, efficient and I understand it completely. I don't understand the second example tho since I haven't studied "stack" yet but for sure I'm studying it right now. I can't thank you more for ur answers.

Answer (score 0):

One way using `crosstab`

```
In [685]: pd.crosstab(df.Range, df.Answer).stack()
Out[685]:
Range  Answer
<30    maybe     0
       no        1
       yes       2
>30    maybe     2
       no        0
       yes       1
dtype: int64
```

Or, `groupby`

```
In [690]: df.groupby(['Range', 'Answer']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).stack()
Out[690]:
Range  Answer
<30    maybe     0
       no        1
       yes       2
>30    maybe     2
       no        0
       yes       1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Beautifull, It works awesomely for 2 variables, will wait to see if there's something like this for multiple columns against one or I will stick with this answer. Thankyou very much